# Member variabes which hold pointers to other member variables / Recursive AI for a simple Game

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, copy-constructor

I am implementing a simple AI for a Game.
The basic idea is:

1. At each state of the game, determine the list of possible actions
2. Store actions in some kind of collection
3. Advance in the game / make moves, while recursively adding new Nodes (GameState) to the StateTree.
4. If no further actions could be determined, the branch of the tree is finished and win/loose conditions will be checked (not implemented yet, but they are very simple)

I am not sure about this constructor (see the complete code sheet below):

```
GameState(GameState * parent, Action & action)
```

The idea is to determine a list of next steps on the higher level of recursion and store the instructions to the AI in a generic list of "Action", which stores two pointers: one to the source game object and the other to the target object. Actions can then be executed in a batch.

The code below is almost complete and should give the idea of what I would like to do.

I am more experienced in Java and have already implemented similar logic, but this task should be solved in C++ and at the moment I am experiencing some technical difficulties.

Addition:
1. If the constructor method I've mentioned is incorrect / bad designed, what is the proper way to implement it? I would like to have GameStates, which "know" what action created them. Since my Actions are created in a parent GameState and store pointers to data structures of THAT state, they are still pointing to the same objects, after they are copied in the constructor. So this kind of logic seems to be wrong. What is the proper way to achieve the behavior I've described? It would help me for example to invert the action, while staying in the same GameState.
2. Any common suggestions to my code? Any suggestions to make it more elegant? Any obvious mistakes that I simply don't recognize?

```
// class GameState.h:
class GameState {

private:
    // The "Foos" are some sort of collection: vector, deque, whatever
    Foo f1;
    Foo f2;
    Action ownAction;
    std::vector<Action> nextActions;

    // Pointer to the previous GameState
    GameState * prevState;
    // Collection of pointers to the next GameStates
    vector<GameState*> nextStates;

public:
    GameState(GameState * parent, Action & action);
    GameState(const GameState & obj);
    void prepare();
    void advance();
    ...
}

// GameState.cpp
GameState::GameState(GameState * parent, Action & action)
{
    this->prevState = parent; // pointer to previous GameState
    this->f1 = parent->f1; // game data container
    this->f2 = parent->f2; // game data container
    this->nextActions = std::vector<Action>(); // we'll determine new next actions in this GameState

    // !!! PROBLEM: pointers stored in the action are still pointing to the game containers of the parent state!
    // What is the proper way to pass an action to the next GameState?
    this->ownAction = action;
    this->visited = parent->visited;
}

GameState::prepare()
{
    // Check game conditions 
    // and create a list of next possible Actions
    if (condition1) {
        nextActions.push_back(Action(&f1, &f2));
    }

    ...

    // there are different kinds of actions
    // which all inherit from the same parent class
    // so I just write "Action" for simplicity
}

GameState::advance()
{
    ownAction.execute(); // execute own action -> alter own state
    prepare(); // prepare a list of next actions

    for(size_t i = o; nextActions.size(); ++i) {
        if (!nextActions.at(i).inverted(ownAction)) { // no steps back are allowed!
            // passing the copy of the altered state and the action to the next level
            GameState * nextState = new GameState(this, nextActions.at(i));
            nextState->advance();
            nextStates.push_back(nextState); // storing the pointer to the next GameState
        }
    }
}

// Action.h
class Action {

private:
    Foo * src;
    Foo * tgt;

public:
    Action(Foo * src, Foo * tgt);
    Action(const Action & obj);
    ~Action();
    void execute();
    bool inverted(Action & other);
}

// Action.cpp    
Action::Action(Foo * src, Foo * tgt)
{
    this->src = src;
    this->tgt = tgt;
}

Action::Action(const Action & obj)
{
    this->src = obj.src;
    this->tgt = obj.tgt;
}

Action::execute()
{
    // something like this:
    tgt.push_back(src.top());
    src.pop();
    // moving values from the one referenced container
    // into another referenced container
}
```

Edited the code, removed unnecessary parts.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Would like to add, that the constructor method I've mentioned in my post is supposed to take an Action, so each GameState would "know" which action created it.

Comment: Please describe your "technical difficulties" and remove all code that's not immediately related to those difficulties.

Comment: I found a question hidden in the code, however it seems to be related to some `Foo` pointers in `Action`. What is `Foo`?

Comment: @tobi303 To make it simple, Foo is a std::vector, which holds some game objects, which are moved between vectors during the game.

Comment: @molbdnilo I removed some parts. Is it better now?

Comment: You say that you don't want the copy of the Action to have pointers to the same objects that the original Action had. You say what you don't want, but you didn't say what you want.

Comment: @RaymondChen

GameState * nextState = new GameState(this, nextActions.at(i));

After the execution of this line, I'd like to have **nextState**, which holds an Action, which points to the objects of the **nextState**, but not to the objects of it's parent.

Comment: Then do that. One way: After copying the Action, update the pointers. Or have a new method `copy_to_new_owner`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I was thinking about that, but how can I determine the corresponding objects? Something like compare referenced objects to Action's own copied objects value by value and then update pointers, when objects are found? Seems a little bit ugly... :)

Comment: How you do it is up to you. If you're more familiar with Java, you can first figure out how to solve the problem in Java, and then translate the solution to C++.